# Regex to Match Acronyms like E U , E.U

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a regular expression that will match values such as E U, E.U, U S A, U.S.A, M.B.B.S, M B B S, etc

I found below regex but it matches the E.U., E.U.AA not E.U and E.U.A.A
@"\b(?:[a-zA-Z].){2,}"

Any help, please

Comment: Are all those acronyms written in upper case? Then you won't need to match a-z. But you do need to match dots and spaces

Comment: upper or lower case both are allowed,

Comment: Try to match \. instead of . - . matches everything including the comma.

Comment: `\b(?:[A-Z][\.\s]?){2,}`

Comment: Can you explain (in terms a computer would understand) how you can see the difference between an acronym and a regular word?

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Regex tools like https://regex101.com can help you to identify the mistake you made building the regex. It's pretty much that the matches sequence matches "everything" because you included "." instead of "." so the comma is matched as well.

The tools are very useful since you can input test data to match against as well. Here you go try this one.

```
\b(?:[a-zA-Z\.\s]){2,}
```